# Node.js npm error on windows command line

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed node.js through windows installer. 
When i try to execute npm command in the console the below error getting printed.

Please guide me to install it properly on windows 7 32-bit machine.

I tried uninstalling the node package several times and installed but executing nmp command prints the same below error.

Are there any path variables that i should set here? The documentation says while installing node.msi it automatically sets the path. Where exactly i am going wrong?

C:\Users\Lakshmikanth.Reddy> npm

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${user.email}
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmconf\npmconf.js:423:13
    at String.replace (native)
    at envReplace (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmconf\npmconf.js:418:12)
    at parseField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmconf\npmconf.js:397:7)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmconf\npmconf.js:339:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmconf\npmconf.js:338:21)
    at ConfigChain.addString (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmconf\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmconf\npmconf.js:327:10)
    at fs.js:271:14


C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:32


throw new Error('npm.load() required')
          ^
Error: npm.load() required
    at Object.npm.config.get (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:32:11)
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:51:40)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:342:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:272:26)
```

Comment: Help me to resolve this error.

Comment: first off, tell us what you are trying to do... or what module you are trying to install... it will help a lot. Second put more detail on to your questions instead of just plonking down a massive wall of error messages... Remember to put what you are trying to do. or you are just going to get down voted and no ones going to answer your question.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The error in question:

> Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${user.email}

means that the `${user.email}` variable in your `.npmrc` is not mapped to a real value.

Use the following steps to troubleshoot:

- Find .npmrc and npmrc

  - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
- Open both .npmrc and npmrc
- Look for the variable in question:

  - `${user.email}`
- Change it to a string:

  - "user@example.com"
- Save both files
- Retry `npm`

**References**

- [Troubleshooting npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: I was having a similar problem with the vairable "${PAL:DataDir}" just renaming the npmrc (or removing) did solve the problem. see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7468